# Any ideas on how to filter out the empty and nil values from JSON object?

Tags: arrays, json, swift, jsondecoder

I am making a network call that returns 20 optional ingredients. Each ingredient that isn't nil, I want to add to an array. The only way I can think of is using 20 if let statements for all 20 and then filtering out the empty strings. Is there an easier way to do all this? When I make the Network call, I don't know which values will be nil so I have to return all 20. I can't change the API. I would love to hear y'all ideas.

You can see an example of the data I am trying to filter in the link below

https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/lookup.php?i=52772

My model:

```
struct Meal : Codable {
var meals : [meals]
}
struct meals : Codable {
var strMeal : String
var strMealThumb : String
var idMeal : String
var strInstructions : String
var strIngredient1 : String?
var strIngredient2 : String?
var strIngredient3 : String?
var strIngredient4 : String?
var strIngredient5 : String?
var strIngredient6 : String?
var strIngredient7 : String?
var strIngredient8 : String?
var strIngredient9 : String?
var strIngredient10 : String?
var strIngredient11 : String?
var strIngredient12 : String?
var strIngredient13 : String?
var strIngredient14 : String?
var strIngredient15 : String?
var strIngredient16 : String?
var strIngredient17 : String?
var strIngredient18 : String?
var strIngredient19 : String?
var strIngredient20 : String?
var strMeasure1 : String?
var strMeasure2 : String?
var strMeasure3 : String?
var strMeasure4 : String?
var strMeasure5 : String?
var strMeasure6 : String?
var strMeasure7 : String?
var strMeasure8 : String?
var strMeasure9 : String?
var strMeasure10 : String?
var strMeasure11 : String?
var strMeasure12 : String?
var strMeasure13 : String?
var strMeasure14 : String?
var strMeasure15 : String?
var strMeasure16 : String?
var strMeasure17 : String?
var strMeasure18 : String?
var strMeasure19 : String?
var strMeasure20 : String?
}
```

Answer (score 3):

That is a seriously hideous data model.

I'd suggest remapping it to an array of ingredient/measure tuples, and using compactMap to get rid of the nil/empty values. Your code would have to explicitly build your arrays of tuples, and then filter/compactMap the ones where either the ingredient or the measure is empty/nil.

I am assuming that strIngredient1 goes with strMeasure1, strIngredient2 goes with strMeasure2, etc, all the way up to strIngredient20 and strMeasure20?

So it would be bad if you filtered out strIngredient7 but not strMeasure7, since then the ingredients and measures would not align any more, correct?